# code for greatest common divisor doesn't output anything

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, greatest-common-divisor

I've written code for finding greatest common divisor:

```
def gcd(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return a
    else:
        return gcd(b, a%b)
```

However, grader doesn't accept it saying that it doesn't output anything. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I fix it?

Most of these online judges expect output on stdout so you will actually need to output something...

```
print(gcd(2, 6))
```

Comment: But it is a specific example. My code should output for all test cases

Comment: @Fadai Mammadov Then take input like `a = int(input())` and `b=int(input())` then call the function `print(gcd(a,b))`